# When elements don't respond to CSS design. Is the issue usually from the frame work.(Bootstrap in this case)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

([Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Ojomiba/pen/OOjLJJ))

I am building a random quote machine, but I am having challenges with the 
positioning of some elements.

1. My font awesome icons are not responding to my coding for their layouts.
2. My footer text is also not responding to my text alignments or color adjustments.

#### HTML:

```
<body class="body">
 <div class="container"> <div class="quote-box"><p class="quote-text">When the Student is ready, the teacher will appear</p>
    <div class="footer">-Zen Proverb
    </div>
  <i class=" fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
  <button>New quote</button>
  </div>

   <hr/> 
 <div class="footer"> By Ojomiba</div>

</body>
```

#### CSS:

```
.body{background-color:blue;}

p{font-size:25px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:30px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
color:blue;
}

.quote-box{background-color:white;
height:150px;
width:550px;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
display:table;
border-radius:10px;
font-weight:800;
padding:auto;
}
button{margin-top:90px;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-left:65%;
height:40px;
border-radius:5px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
background-color:brown;}

.fa{
  float:left;
  padding:auto;
height:20px;
border-radius:5px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
color:brown;
  border:none;
  margin-top:90px;
background-color:white;
}
   .footer{color:blue;
     text-align:center;
     display:block;
     margin left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;}

hr{margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;}
```

Comment: Your HTML/CSS has errors and your example doesn't appear to utilize Bootstrap in the way you're suggesting that it may be causing the issue (if you remove the Bootstrap CSS it doesn't seem to change much). Be more explicit as to what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Might depend on various factors why the style sheet isn't rendering as you'd like. First check the basic things like:

1. The precedence of the style sheets. If the bootstrap css file comes after your css file, some bootstrap styles might take precedence over yours. So make sure your css files comes after bootstrap's.
2. Check to see if there's any JS that touches on those particular elements you're trying to style